# post to page to login using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using python and beautifulsoup (new to both!), and I want to login to a suppliers website.

So their form looks like (simplified):

```
<form name=loginform action=/index.html method="post">

<input name=user>
<input name=pass">

</form>
```

Is there a way to keep track for cookies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do some more reading.

Read about `urllib2`  That's what you use to do a POST to login.  If you know the `<input>` names, you don't need Beautiful Soup.  http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Beautiful Soup is what you use to parse a page of results.  After you login.  After you post the real request.

Comment: ah ok, so urllib will store cookies also?

Comment: http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/03/automatic-site-login-using-python-urllib2/

Has a nice example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8):

Use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) -- that's just the best (3rd party) Python library for interacting with web forms, keeping track of cookies &c.