# How to extract text from a web page that requires logging in using python and beautiful soup?

Tags: python, urllib2, beautifulsoup

i have to retrieve some text from a website called morningstar.com . To access that data i have to log in. Once i log in and provide the url  of the web page  ,  i get the HTML text of a normal user (not logged in).As a result am not able to accees that information . ANy solutions ?

Comment: You have to provide a cookie to the page.  Exactly how to do that with Python and beautifulsoap, I'm not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [post to page to login using beautiful soup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340190/post-to-page-to-login-using-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is for parsing html once you've already fetched it.  You can fetch the html using any standard url fetching library.  I prefer curl, as you tagged your post, python's built-in urllib2 also works well.

If you're saying that after logging in the response html is the same as for those who are not logged in, I'm gonna guess that your login is failing for some reason.  If you are using urllib2, are are you making sure to store the cookie properly after your first login and then passing this cookie to urllib2 when you are sending the request for the data?

It would help if you posted the code you are using to make the two requests (the initial login, and the attempt to fetch the data).

Comment: actually i'm not logging in using python.I just do a manual log in using the browser and then fetch the URL.Then i feed the URL to beautiful soup. When i look at the contents of the html, it is the html code for "normal users" . I do not know how to use the cookie feature and store it. Would really appreciate it if u could give some info on how to use cookies here

Comment: Oh, this is your problem.  Cookie handling is managed separately for each User-Agent (eg. your browser, curl, urllib2, etc).  So if you are fetching the url with urllib2 and want to be logged in, you must make sure that urllib2 has your login cookie.  The simplest way to do this is to first login using urllib2 and store this cookie before you do your second request.  For info on how to do this, see [urllib2: The Missing Manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)