# Python-Logging in to a site while scraping it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am signing into my account at www.goodreads.com to scrape the list of books from my profile.

However, when I go to the goodreads page, even if I am logged in, my scraper gets only the home page. It cannot log in to my account. How do I redirect it to my account?

Edit:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.goodreads.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())

[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('script')]
print(soup.get_text())
```

If I run this code, I get only till the homepage, I cannot login to the my profile, even if I am already logged in to the browser.

What do I do to log in from a scraper?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you are using. We can't do much without knowing exactly what you're doing. Make sure you obfuscate your username and password, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340190/post-to-page-to-login-using-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you go to the site there is something called **sessions** that contains information about your accout ( not exactly but something like that ) and your browser can use them so every time that you go to the main page you are logged in , but you code doesn't use sessions and these things so you should do everything from the first

1) go to mainpage 2) log in 3) gathering your data

and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340190/post-to-page-to-login-using-beautiful-soup)  showed how to login to your account

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Goodreads has an [API](https://www.goodreads.com/api) that you might want to use instead of trying to log in and scrape the site's HTML. It's formatted in XML, so you can still use `BeautifulSoup` - just make sure you have `lxml` installed and use it as the parser. You'll need to register for a developer key, and also register your application, but then you're good to go.

Comment: I do use lxml, and I can use the API, but I would like to learn how to login into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib2 or requests library to login and then scrape the response. In my experience using requests is a lot easier.

Here's a good explanation on logging in using both urllib2 and requests:

[How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage)