# How to Authenticate OAUTH2 to use API in Python?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, hl7-fhir

I am trying to connect with a FHIR server to use the API and pull information.

So far I can connect, but it requires me to authenticate using a browser and entering my User and Pass. I am looking for a way to automate this so I can authenticate without having to login the browser.

Currently I am using https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/client-py to do this, but I am open to other solutions. My current code to do this is the following:

```
from fhirclient import client

def connect_to_fhir():
    settings = {
            'app_id': 'MyApp',
            'api_base': 'https://endpointurl.com/api/',
            'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:8000/fhir-app/',
            'patient_id': 'test',
        }
    smart = client.FHIRClient(settings=settings)

    print(smart.authorize_url)

    smart.handle_callback(input('Authorize and paste callback url here: '))
    return smart
```

Comment: Your ***"redirect_uri"*** have to be reachable from the internet, this seems not to be the case?

Comment: It seems to be working, When it prints the authorize url I go to that link, log in, and then copy and paste the call back url. I have no problems authenticating this way, I just want to have a process where I dont have to manually log in.

Comment: I got your point. You have to inspect the *login* page html content and find out which auth, usually `<form action=/login`, this site uses. Relevant [post-to-page-to-login-using-beautiful-soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340190/post-to-page-to-login-using-beautiful-soup?r=SearchResults&s=2|54.6564)

Comment: I just this using requests. When I try to do a post on the authorize_url I get: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}